# Reducing database hits in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, `projects` and `words` where `project has_many :words` (words is really just a model that holds the quantity of words written each day for each project.

I have a view that I build like this, which shows all the days from start to end in the project and how many, if any words were written on that day:

```
<% project_range(@project.start, @project.end).each do |day| %>
    <%= day %>
    <%= get_word_count_by_date(@project, day ) %>
<% end %>
```

And in my helper:

```
def project_range(start, finish)
  project_days = (start..finish).collect
end

def get_word_count_by_date(project, date)
  word_count = Word.find_by_project_id_and_wrote_on(project, date)
  if word_count
    word_count.quantity
  else
    0
  end
end
```

Trouble is, in the view, that hits my database a lot. For example, if the project is 30 days, I get:

```
  Word Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-01' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-02' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-03' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-04' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-05' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-06' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-07' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-08' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-09' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-10' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-11' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-12' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-13' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-14' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-15' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-16' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-17' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-18' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-19' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-20' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-21' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-22' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-23' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-24' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-25' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-26' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-27' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-28' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-29' LIMIT 1
  Word Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."project_id" = 2 AND "words"."wrote_on" = '2011-09-30' LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way to do this without querying every single day in the length of the project? I tried starting by loading all of a project's words first, but couldn't figure out how to get the days with zero in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a block helper to keep it clean and avoid looking them up:

```
def project_range(project, start, finish, &blk)
  words = project.words.where(:wrote_on => start..finish)
  word_map = words.index_by(&:wrote_on)
  for day in start..finish
    word_count = word_map[day] ? word_map[day].quantity : 0
    blk.call(day, word_count)
  end
end
```

Then use it like

```
<% project_range(project, start, finish) do |day, word_count| %>
   <%= day %>
   <%= word_count %>
<% end %>
```

You could also clean up the helper a bit (avoid having SQL in it), maybe by passing the list of pre-fetched words or using a `scope`

EDIT: m_x suggested the `start..finish where` clause on `wrote_on` which is cleaner!

Comment: ah, i was just about to post the same answer... plus, you can use     `where(:wrote_on => @project.start..@project.end)`,it will result in a single SQL statement with the IN token.

Comment: Ooh, very nice i'll make sure to use that next opportunity i get!  Though one thought, if you're looking at a huge date range - wouldn't it be best to still do the range query rather than an IN query

Comment: Having a little trouble with this ... it doesn't like the .each on the start..finish (said it was undefined method). I surrounded the range with () and then it told me `can't convert Date into Integer`

Comment: this is the error it gives as written : `undefined method `each' for Fri, 30 Sep 2011:Date`

Comment: Sorry justin, i wrote this off the top of my head - fixed above.  `for` loop instead of each and `index_by` instead of `index`

Comment: No trouble! Thanks for your help. That got rid of the first error, but I think it's having trouble using a date as a key? I'm getting `can't convert Date into Integer`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3185/discussion-between-kristian-pd-and-justinm)

Comment: my mistake, the code i've given should generate a BETWEEN as seen here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions (see 2.3.2 range conditions)

Answer (score 3):

This is a "n+1" problem... What you want to do is join words and projects in your query so that all the words for each project are included in the result set.

Assuming that your project "has_many :words":

```
@project = Project.find(:id, :include => :words)
```

Now the words collection on each project will be pre-populated with the words in just 1 query.

Read more under the "Eager Loading of Associations" http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Jesse, my hesitation with this approach is that a) he's going to grab all the words for the entire history of the project (not just the one he's looking at) and b) he's going to have to iterate over them in some manner to find the day's he's looking for.  Other than that, agreed that this is definitely the way to go to load all your associations up front.

Comment: @Kristian: good point .... maybe add a custom conditions... like `:conditions => ["words.wrote_on >= ? and words.wrote_on <= ?", start,end]`

Comment: Unfortunately that would modify the original project query rather than the loaded associations (Plus I believe you're thinking of `.joins`). If you had a project with no words in the date range you're looking for, the project would not be returned.  He also needs to address the `0 word count` day problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like:

```
@words = @project.words.where("wrote_on >= ? and wrote_on <= ?", start, end)
```

and than use [group_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to display them in the view:

```
@words.group_by(&:wrote_on).each do |day, word|
<%= day %>
<%= word.quantity %>
end
```

Comment: Only trouble with this is it doesn't seem to display days with no word counts ... and that's the trouble. I need those.

Comment: I've edited the question. I forgot the field name. It should work fine